# Why javascript indexOf method give me wrong output

Tags: javascript, arrays

If i us "var" to declare array given as below. Why give me 6

```js
var name = ['Rohan', 'Google', 'Student'];
console.log(name.indexOf('Google'));
```

> Otput is 6

If i use "let" to declare array give me right answer why

```js
let name = ['Rohan', 'Google', 'Student'];
console.log(name.indexOf('Google'));
```

> Otput is 1

Comment: the one where you have use `let` is correct, have you declared the variable `name` is any other part of the code? Javascript can actually pick it up and then show the result

Comment: Do you use the variable `name` anywhere else?

Comment: `var name`  refers to [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name). It will always be a string. If you do `console.log(name)`, it will show `"Rohan,Google,Student"` and not `['Rohan', 'Google', 'Student']`. Please check the duplicates for more details.

Comment: that's super weird, i think the problem is that javascript considered the first name (var) as string not array because when you do ```typeof(name)``` it gives **string**, which explains why indexof is returning 6 ( because G of Google is the 7th character, and when you declare it using let, typeof returns **Object** which is what you want

Comment: no i don't before because in my JS page has only tow line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of naming your variable as `name` change it to some other name and you will get a right result.

```
var myArray = ['Rohan', 'Google', 'Student'];
console.log(myArray.indexOf('Google'));
```

The reason is there is some global variable called `name` whose result is being shown (If you check developer console and search `window.name` you can know what that variable is).

`var` has global scope in this case pointing to `window` object.

And in case of `let name`, we should know that `let` has **local scope** within the context so this time name points to your array not global name. Infact **ES6** introduced `let`, `const` to avoid global spacing issue that we were facing with `var`

Comment: working grate. thanks but why came case ?

Comment: Hello @Gagan why came case??? means :)

Comment: i am facing problem only "name" keyword

Comment: If i use "namee" or "abc" it's working

Comment: If you are on windows machine, use `CTRL+SHIFT+I` or right click and inspect element.
Then in console, simply type `name` and see what you get :) by default name has global scope and in your case it is pointing to the global object called `window`, so writing `window.name` or `name` will point to that string or array and that's why you are getting the index as 6.

Comment: Yes, because `name` variable is attached to `window` object.